# "Is that OK [with/to] you?"

Tags: differences

What's the difference between “Is that OK **to** you?” and “Is that OK **with** you?”

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiom for "to" is "Does that seem ok to you?" or "Does that look ok to you?"  The first is a query about the general propriety of something:

> They fired him with no notice.  Does that seem **ok to** you?

The second may be used to ask about an uncertainty the speaker has about correct usage:

> On the second line, the word *canceled* is spelled with one "l"; does
>   that look **ok to** you?

"Is that ok with you?" asks whether you have any objections to a situation or a proposal:

> We're going to delay the board meeting until next week.  Is that **ok
>   with** you?